# Automating version increase of R packages

Tags: r, package

**Problem**

I am developing an R package and I want to increase the version automatically each time I build it. I want that to be able to associate my results to package versions. For now I was using my own *ugly* function to do that.

*My question is:* is there a way to do it better? Or, should I avoid doing that in general?

**Another option**

Another option I was thinking of is to install my package (hosted in github) using ´devtools::install_github´ and then save with my results (or adding to plots) the GithubSHA1 that is saved in the installed DESCRIPTION file.

For example I can get the version and GithubSHA1 like that for the ´devtools´ package:

```
read.dcf(file=system.file("DESCRIPTION", package="devtools"), 
         fields=c("Version", "GithubSHA1"))
 ##      Version    GithubSHA1                                
 ## [1,] "1.5.0.99" "3ae58a2a2232240e67b898f875b8da5e57d1b3a8"
```

**My tries so far**

I wrote the following function to produce a new DESCRIPTION file, with updated version and date. (Increasing the major version is something I don't mind increasing per hand)

```r
incVer <- function(pkg, folder=".", increase="patch"){
    ## Read DESCRIPTION from installed package ´pkg´ and make new one on the specified
    ## ´folder´. Two options for ´increase´ are "patch" and "minor"
    f <- read.dcf(file=system.file("DESCRIPTION", package=pkg),
                  fields=c("Package", "Type", "Title", "Version", "Date", 
                           "Author", "Maintainer", "Description", "License", 
                           "Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"))
    curVer <- package_version(f[4])
    if(increase == "patch") {
        curVer[[1,3]] <- ifelse(is.na(curVer$patchlevel), 1, curVer$patchlevel + 1)

    } else if (increase == "minor") {
        curVer[[1,2]] <- ifelse(is.na(curVer$minor), 1, curVer$minor + 1)
        curVer[[1,3]] <- 0
    } else {
        stop(paste("Can not identify the increase argument: " , increase))
    }

    f[4] <- toString(curVer)
    ## Update also the date
    f[5] <- format (Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d")
    write.dcf(f, file=paste(folder, "DESCRIPTION", sep="/"))
}
```

Comment: I don't find much ugliness here, similar approach is utilized by the Roxygen2 package.

Comment: But roxygen2 does not deal with the DESCRIPTION file, except for the collate field, right?

Comment: I observed that roxygen2 sometimes reformats my DESCRIPTION files significantly, e.g. it breaks lines etc.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `match.arg(increase, choices = c("patch","minor","major"))`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using git, then you can use git tags to create a version string. This is how we generate the version string of our `igraph` library:

```
git describe HEAD --tags | rev | sed 's/g-/./' | sed 's/-/+/' | rev
```

It gives you a format like this:

```
0.8.0-pre+131.ca78343
```

`0.8.0-pre` is the last tag on the current branch. (The last released version was 0.7.1, and we create a `-pre` tag immediately after the release tag.) `131` is the number of commits since the last tag. `ca78343` is the first seven character of the hex id of the last commit.

This would be great, except that you cannot have version strings like this in R packages, R does not allow it. So for R we transform this version string using the following script: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/develop/interfaces/R/tools/convertversion.sh

Essentially it creates a version number that is larger than the last released version and smaller than the next versions (the one in the `-pre` tag). From `0.8.0-pre+131.ca78343` it creates

```
0.7.999-131
```

where `131` is the number of commits since the last release.

I put the generation of the `DESCRIPTION` file in a Makefile. This replaces the date, and the version number:

```
VERSION=$(shell ./tools/convertversion.sh)

igraph/DESCRIPTION: src/DESCRIPTION version_number
        sed 's/^Version: .*$$/Version: '$(VERSION)'/' $<     | \
        sed 's/^Date: .*$$/Date: '`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`'/' > $@
```

This is quite convenient, you don't need to do anything, except for adding the release tags and
the `-pre` tags.

Btw. this was mostly worked out by my friend and igraph co-developer, Tamás Nepusz, so the credit is his.

Comment: yow, complicated (but looks quite useful)

Comment: Not really complicated, that is the thing. Once you have the scripts, you only need to add two git tags, one of them you would add anyway. It is really a pity, that R does not support better version strings, though. :(

Comment: Btw. this also handles "released" versions well, so if you checkout a release, then the `git` one-liner above gives the exact versions number without the `+` and the commit id, or the `-pre`. Btw.2. in our package we also include an `igraph.version()` function that gives the correct version string, i.e. `0.8.0-pre+131.ca78343`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I took some time to go into the details and the way you describe it is really easy to understand. I will probably use some parts of your answer (I have to learn to use `sed` some time soon). I was hoping to get an answer relying more on R and less on git tags. I was sure I was missing an argument in `devtools::build`,  or something. If nothing comes up, I will be really glad to give you the bounty!

Comment: Well, I think it is in general a good idea to tie the version numbers to the version control system. You could write your own `build_package` function based on `devtools::build`, but if you don't use the VCS revisions, then it will be impossible to go back to a given package version later, which is pretty much the main point in using version numbers.

Comment: Btw. you don't need to use `sed`, you can write the extra script in R if you want. The reason for using `sed` and other Unix tools is that they start fast, while R has a long startup time, so I tend not to use it in simple scripts like this.

Comment: I agree about the VCS and having a connection btw verstion numbers and VCS. I think I will do exactly what you are proposing, writing a wrapper to build_package. Maybe make it commit and tag into git.

Comment: About the unix tools, it is something that is in my todo list in a long time.

Comment: @alko989: I think making `build_package` commit is a bad idea. First you want to build the package, so that you can test that it works. If it works (most of the time it does not, for the first try), then you can commit. Typically you build a lot of times, before you commit. Also, with the setup detailed above, you do not need to tag each commit. You only tag "released" versions. My method ensures that all commits in between will get meaningful version numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56116/discussion-between-alko989-and-gabor-csardi).

Comment: @Gabor Csardi, have anything changed in your versioning since you answer because file `convertversion.sh` from link cannot be found?

Comment: @Taz Yeah, I gave up on it. :)

Comment: @Gabor Csardi, ok, but how do you handle versioning problem now?

Comment: I bump the version manually. I don't bump it for every commit.

Answer (score 4):

For a simpler approach, consider using the [`crant`](https://github.com/muxspace/crant) tool with the `-u` switch. For instance,

```
crant -u 3
```

will increment the third component of the version by one. There is also Git and SVN integration, and a bunch of other useful switches for roxygenizing, building, checking etc..

Comment: Thanks for that! I will take a look. (It seems that in the documentation you use `rant` instead of `crant`, am I missing something or is it just a typo?)

Comment: @alko989: Yes, that's a typo. Care to fix it? :-)

Comment: I fixed and made a pull request.

Comment: @alko989: Thanks. I can't merge your PR, but I'm sure the owner will eventually.

Answer (score 2):

As auto-incrementing version numbering is [not going to be built](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/501) into the `devtools` package, I figured out a way based on [Gabor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24274717/4575331) (the link to igraph in his answer is dead btw).

When I am about to commit to our repository, I run this bash script to set the date to today and to set the version number based on the latest tag, the .9000 suffix (as suggested [here in the book *R Packages*](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) by Hadley Wickham) and the number of commits within that tag:

```
echo "••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••"
echo "• Updating package date and version number •"
echo "••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••"
sed -i -- "s/^Date: .*/Date: $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')/" DESCRIPTION
# get latest tags
git pull --tags --quiet
current_tag=`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | sed 's/v//'`
current_commit=`git describe --tags | sed 's/.*-\(.*\)-.*/\1/'`
# combine tag (e.g. 0.1.0) and commit number (like 40) increased by 9000 to indicate beta version
new_version="$current_tag.$((current_commit + 9000))" # results in 0.1.0.9040
sed -i -- "s/^Version: .*/Version: ${new_version}/" DESCRIPTION
echo "First 3 lines of DESCRIPTION:"
head -3 DESCRIPTION
echo
# ... after here more commands like devtools::document() and git commit
```

To be clear - this script actually makes these changes to the `DESCRIPTION` file.

EDIT: support for hundreds - now just increases the commit sequence number by 9000. So commit #120 in tag `v0.6.1` leads to `0.6.1.9120`.

Comment: Have you tried having this command run via git's 'post-commit' hook?

Comment: No, but definitely interested. How would that work? How could I use that to update a file, and why prefer that over doing it locally? Just curious what the benefits are :)

Comment: My understanding is limited, but hooks allow code to run automatically at different points of VC updating.  So you should be able to set a hook that runs your script each time you commit. Seems like you'd want this as a pre-commit hook. Hope that helps you get oriented.